# onSubmit handler function not working as expected, shows error for split second and disappears, in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am a beginner in React.js and I'm trying to implement a delete functionality for an app. On clicking the button, the form gets submitted and the function runs, however it shows an error in the console which is there for a split second so I couldn't read it. I have tried `setTimeout` to atleast see the error but it has no effect. The error just appears for a fraction of a second in the console and then disappears. The code is:

```js
const Note = ({object}) => {
    const {title, desc} = object;

     const handleDel = (e, object)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(object)
    }
    return (
        <>
          <div className="single-note">
              <div>
                  <h1>{title}</h1>
                  <p>{desc}</p>
              </div>
                
              <form onSubmit={()=>handleDel(object)}>
                  <button type="submit" className="submit">
                      <FaRegTrashAlt/>
                  </button>
              </form> 
          </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Note
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you missed to pass the event and it is trying to invoke `preventDefault` on the `object` param that is passed. Try the below code:

```
onSubmt={(e) => handleDel(e,object)}
```